# justify to the right input boxes and select drop down menu?

Tags: html, css, input, justify

Tried to find a question with an answer in this subject, but I was not able to.

I am trying to justify the input boxes and select drop down menu to the right. I tried couple of things like position and floating the label right and input and select left to no avail.

```
            <div class="tabContainer clearfix">
                <form>
                    <select name="selectionField" id="selectionField">
                        <option value="membership1">$9.95(USD) for 3 days (non-recurring)</option>
                        <option value="membership2">$89.95(USD) for 1 year (non-recurring)</option>
                        <option value="membership3">$34.95(USD) for 1 Month (recurring)</option>
                    </select>
                    <p><label for="credit_card">Credit Card #: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="credit_card" id="credit_card" placeholder="Credit Card Number" maxlength="16" size="20" autofocus required /></p>
                    <p><label for="cvv2InputField">CVV2 Number:&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cvv2InputField" id="cvv2InputField" maxlength="4" size="4" value onfocus="explainCVV2(this, 1)" onblur="explainCVV2(this, 0)" required /></p>
                    <p><label for="expirationMonth">Expires:&nbsp;</label>
                    <select name="exp_month" id="exp_month">
                        <option value></option>
                            <option value="01">01</option>
                            <option value="02">02</option>
                            <option value="03">03</option>
                            <option value="04">04</option>
                            <option value="05">05</option>
                            <option value="06">06</option>
                            <option value="07">07</option>
                            <option value="08">08</option>
                            <option value="09">09</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                            </select>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <select name="exp_year">
                            <option value></option>
                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                            <option value="2019">2019</option>
                            <option value="2020">2020</option>
                            <option value="2021">2021</option>
                            <option value="2022">2022</option>
                            <option value="2023">2023</option>
                            <option value="2024">2024</option>
                            <option value="2025">2025</option>
                        </select>
                    <p><label for="name_on_card">Name on Card:&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name_on_card" id="name_on_card" placeholder="Full Name" maxlength="35" size="30"/></p> 
                    <p><label for="address1">Address:&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" name="adress1" id="adress1" maxlength="35" size="30"/></p>
                    <p><label for="address2">City:&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" name="adress2" id="adress2" maxlength="35" size="30"/></p>
                    <p><label for="zipcode">Postal Code:&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" maxlength="35" size="30"/></p>
                    <p><label for="country">Country:&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" name="country" id="country" maxlength="35" size="30"/></p>
                    <p><label for="email">Email Address:&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" maxlength="35" size="30"/></p>
                </form>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
    .accountSettings {
background: url("../images/searchBg.jpg") repeat scroll left top transparent;
border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-o-border-radius: 6px;
-border-radius: 6px;
padding: 25px;
```

}

```
 .favContent, .homeIntroWrapper {
width: 700px;
margin: -75px auto 0;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-o-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
```

}

```
 .tabContainer {
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
-o-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
/*margin-top: -1px;*/
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
text-decoration: bold;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lucky500/Zkvu7/

all the help would be appreciate it.

Lucky

Comment: Have you tried using a table?

Comment: should I use tables for this example? I have been learning that tables are not good for designs, but maybe on this case, is what's best.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Zkvu7/1/ is it fine for you?

Comment: Thanks Raunak, this is better than what I had!

Comment: I will explain in answer.. what can you do to make it working..

Comment: Tables get a bad rap because people used to design whole webpages with them, which is not the way to go. You want the box model. However, in this case (a form) they are perfect.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is update your html structure to this

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="left-content"></div>
    <div class="right-content">
        <div class="tabContainer clearfix">
        // your content here
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

or you can add

```
<div class="tabContainer clearfix">
   <div class="left-content"> </div>
   <div class="right-content">//your input boxes comes here</div>
</div>
```

The add the corresponding css

```
.main-content {
    width: 100%;
}

.left-content {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.right-content {
    width: 60%;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/Zkvu7/2/